# PHP if statement question (& operator)

Tags: php, operators, if-statement, bit-manipulation

I'm using a function I found online.  What does the & mean in this conditional?

`if ($strength & 8) {
        $consonants .= '@#$%';
    }`

$strength is supposed to be a number 0-8.  The function is intending to use all $consonants concatenations where $strength < 8.  (might explain why the function is not working).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single `&` is the bitwise operator and the double `&&` is the logical. (i.e. Bits that are set in both `$strength` and `8` are set in your example.) It's a lot more complicated than just saying that and it requires an understanding of how binary works.

**EDIT:** Check out [this article](http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/bitwise.htm) for more information on Bitwise operators.

Comment: haha.. damn the extra few seconds it took me to add the link in my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

& is a [bitwise operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) - it's checking to see if the bits that total 8 are set. In this case, `1000`

Answer (score 3):

`&` is a bitwise operator. It combines two values bitwise.

**What is a bitwise operator?**

Every integer is internally represented as a number of bits.

```
1 is 0001
2 is 0010
4 is 0100
8 is 1000
```

And so on. every bit's value is twice as big as the one preceding it.

You can get other numbers by combining bits

```
3 is 0011 (2+1)
5 is 0101 (4+1)
```

A bitwise operation works on every bit in both variables. `&` sets every bit in the result to 1 if it is 1 in *both* values it operates on.

9&5 == 1

because

```
9 == 1001
5 == 0101
----------
1 == 0001
```

| will COMBINE all 1s:

3|5 == 7

```
3 == 0011
5 == 0101
---------
7 == 0111
```

How can yo use it?

Example:

```
define('LOG_WARNING',1);
define('LOG_IO',2);
define('LOG_ALIENATTACKS,4);

$myLogLevel = LOG_WARNING | LOG_ALIENATACKS;
```

Now `$myLogLevel` is a combination of `LOG_WARNING` and `LOG_ALIENATTACK`. You can test it with the `&` operator:

```
if($myLogLevel&LOG_WARNING).... //true
if($myLogLevel&LOG_IO).... //false
if($myLogLevel&LOG_ALIENATTACKS)..../ /true run or your live!!!
```

If you want to know more about the topic search for bitflags and binary operations.

Comment: Good explanations but please also take the time to check your spelling when writing answers.